# Storing numerical value from a binary file into an array- C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

I am trying to read numerical data from a binary file containing 100 double values and store it in an array called myArray. When I print myArray nothing is being shown, as if myArray has never been filled. Any help is appreciated.

```
int main() 
{
    int file_len; 
    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("mybinfile.bin", ios::binary | ios::in); 
    if (!infile.is_open()) 
    {
    cout << "Error in opening the file. " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const int file_len = 100;

        std::vector<char> myVect;
        myVect.resize(file_len);

        int i = 0;
        infile.read((char *) (&temp), sizeof(char));
        myVect[i] = temp;
        while(!infile.eof())
        {

            myVect[i] = temp;
            i++;
            infile.read((char *)  (&temp), sizeof(char));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
        {cout << i << ": " << myVect[i]<< endl;}
    }    
    infile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'temp' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
infile.read((char*)&myArray, file_len * sizeof(double));
```

You pass the **pointer to the pointer** to double. It should be

```
infile.read((char*)myArray, file_len * sizeof(double));
```

Makes me wonder why you didn't see a crash, since writing into random memory almost never turns out well.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've corrected the code. However, the problem is that I have values of 0-255 in the file, and with `infile.read((char *) (&temp), sizeof(char));` I can have the character equivalent to the ascii of the numeric values. How can I directly extract the numeric values into myVect without using type casting?

Comment: @QuestionMark That is just a cast to keep infile.read(...) happy. From your unedited question I assume you like to read a sequence of double. If the writer of the file has the same size and format for doubles you can leave it simply like **double temp; infile-read((char *)&temp,...);**

Comment: @QuestionMark so read into an array of double. See Erik's answer. You need to cast the address to char* when passing to read(), though.  You could do `infile.read( (char*) &myVect[0], file_len * sizeof(double) )` for instance

Comment: @greggo If it's a question the answer is yes

Comment: @Oncaphillis sorry tagged it to you by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example of brute-force serialization and de-serialization. Note that serialization in general is tricky, due to e.g. endianness, different floating-point formats, conversion between decimal text representations and binary and whatnot.

```
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::ofstream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;

string fname("/tmp/doubles.bin");

void write_doubles()
{
    ofstream of;
    of.open(fname.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    double arr[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = static_cast<double>(i+100);
    }

    of.write((char*)arr, 100*sizeof(double));
}

void read_doubles()
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(fname.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    double arr[100];
    ifs.read((char*)arr, 100*sizeof(double));


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << "Arr[i]: " << arr[i] << ", ";
    }

    cout << '\n';


}

int main()
{
    write_doubles();
    read_doubles();

    return 0;
}
```