# Loading in a file skips 3rd and 4th byte, but reads the rest of the file fine

Tags: c++, file

Im attempting to read in a binary file and put it in an array. However when loading in the file it skips the 3rd and 4th byte of the file and reads the rest in fine.

The file contains:

```
30 01 00 20 39 00 20 00 10 01 33 00 00 02 70 00
00 40
```

with the rest of the file filled with 0's

The array contains

```
30 01 39 00 20 00 10 01 33 00 00 02 70 00
40
```

with the rest of the array filled with zeros

It only appears to skip over `00 20` in the third and fourth byte.

Here is the code:

```cpp
uint8_t memory[65536] = { };

void LoadIntoMemory(char* filepath){
    std::ifstream File;
    File.open(filepath);
    for(int i = 0; i < 65536; i ++){
        File >> memory[i];
    }
    File.close();
}
```

The file being loaded will always be 65536 bytes

Comment: Never use `>>` to stream in raw bytes.  Use `File.read` instead.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735428/storing-numerical-value-from-a-binary-file-into-an-array-c